# Continuous ColorAnimation?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I set up a nice ColorAnimation.
When applying AutoReverse = true to it, it even goes from one color to another.

Now I want it to change the color it animates to randomly after every completed runthrough.
How can I achieve this?

btw. I'm attaching my Animation to a storyboard:

```
storyboard.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
storyboard.Children.Add(SpotLightAnimation);
storyboard.Begin(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the forever and just when the animation finish run it again with other colors

Comment: Easy but true.
I assigned a function to the Complete-Event of my SpotLightAnimation which changes the to-value and then starts the animation again.

Comment: The animation is changed so its not the same any more, meaning forever does not good for this case cause it is not the same animation you are running.